# Insert multiple rows - java prepared statement failing

Tags: java, javascript, mysql, rhino

--SOLVED--Turned out to be a problem with our Shareplow install--Thanks for the tries guys--

Per the answer on [Performance of MySQL Insert statements in Java: Batch mode prepared statements vs single insert with multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11389449/performance-of-mysql-insert-statements-in-java-batch-mode-prepared-statements-v) I'm trying to use bulk insert prepared statments. The problem is, only the first row is being inserted.

Relevant piece of my code

```
var sql2 = 'INSERT INTO ' + memtable2 + ' (' + locNameCol2 + ', ' + sectTypeCol + ', '
+ sectPathCol + ') VALUES ';
var cntr = 0;

for (var key in polyObj)//pass sub section paths in an object.
{
  if(cntr){
    sql2 += ',';
  }
  sql2 += '(?,?,?)';
  cntr = 1;
}

var s2 = con2.prepareStatement(sql2);
cntr = 0;
for (var key in polyObj)
{
  indxOffset = 3*cntr;
  s2.setString(indxOffset+1 , fieldNameVal);
  s2.setString(indxOffset+2 , 'Poly');
  s2.setString(indxOffset+3 , polyObj[key]);
  rval += 'index offset ' + indxOffset;
  cntr++;
}
s2.execute();
```

The first row gets inserted fine but no subsequent rows get inserted. When I dump the sql2 string I see that it's getting built correctly (I think) for the number of properties in polyObj. So if polyObj has 3 properties, the sql would be:
`Insert into table (col1, col2, col3) values (?,?,?),(?,?,?),(?,?,?)`
Is there some setting on my database that would prevent multiple row inserts? Am I just doing something wrong? Totally stumped.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not in Groovy. It's a server side JavaScript interpreter called Rhino. As it turns out, the problem was a backend bug with our Shareplow install that was not allowing for updating multiple lines. I had to get our lead developer to fix it. Also, I'm not sure what benefit addBatch will give me as I'm NOT using a batch insert. I'm doing a bulk insert per the above link.

Comment: PS: Java != Javascript   ... ... not even close.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a PreparedStatement with executeBatch() instead.

```
String sql = "insert into foo (x,y,z) values (?,?,?)
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setObject(1, "a1");
ps.setObject(2, "b1");
ps.setObject(3, "c1");
ps.addBatch();
ps.setObject(1, "a2");
ps.setObject(2, "b2");
ps.setObject(3, "c2");
ps.addBatch();
ps.setObject(1, "a3");
ps.setObject(2, "b3");
ps.setObject(3, "c3");
ps.addBatch();
ps.executeBatch();
```

Comment: And I'm not using a batch per the link I initially included. You'll note a marked increase in performance over the method I'm using over batch.