# PHP strtotime returns empty value

Tags: php, strtotime

Well i built my website to write dates to database column in the following format:
2014/04/01

Now i've come to realize this is not helpful when i want to sort by date or manipulate date so i decided to change all date to to timestamps.

i applied the following fix :

```
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TABLE")or(die(mysql_Error()));
while($info = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $newdate = strtotime($info['date']);
        mysql_query("UPDATE TABLE SET date = '$newdate' WHERE id = $info[id]")or(die(mysql_error()));
}
```

the problem is all the date columns are empty now, What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Where are you actually changing the column datatype?

Comment: What's `$info['date']` set to when it fails?

Comment: In the UPDATE statement im replacing the old date with the new timestamp.

Comment: Whats the data type of column `date`?

Comment: why dont use a `date` field date?

Comment: @amphetamachine originally the $info['date'] contains a date like this 2014/04/01 after i run the script date column is empty.

Comment: @Rufinus How do i do that ?

Comment: You do know that by default when MySQL has a null in a datetime column it returns the positively unhelpful "0000-00-00 00:00" value, which `strtotime` can't parse (returns false).

Comment: @amphetamachine the date filed is set to text, i know this is a poor implementation but it accepts any value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's what looks like a syntax error on this line:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE TABLE SET date = '$newdate' WHERE id = $info[id]")
    or(die(mysql_error()));
```

Try changing it to:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE TABLE SET date = '$newdate' WHERE id = {$info['id']}")
    or (die(mysql_error()));
```

The reason is that when interpolating array indices into a string, you must surround them with `{}` or PHP will just try to convert `$info` to a string and insert `[id]` after it, which I'm guessing you didn't intend.

I would also suggest checking the return value for `strtotime`. If it can't parse a date it returns `false` which I'm guessing you don't want inserted back into your database.

Comment: and think about using `pdo` or `mysqli_*` function instead of the deprecated mysql_query. and then you should use prepare statements to prevent from sql injections besides other nice improvments (e.g. speed - prepare once, update many)

Comment: @Rufinus I don't think prepared statements will do anything to improve security here. It seems he's running a one-off script to "fix" the data in the date column using PHP. Still, I agree, it's a good habit to get into.

Comment: @amphetamachine right. this is why i mentioned the speed gain. if he prepare the statement once and execute only with the different values.

Comment: @Rufinus Reusing prepared statements won't increase speed over straight querying; the same amount of SQL gets sent over the wire regardless.

Comment: @amphetamachine not really, you spare the mysql server to parse the same query over and over again. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11389449/performance-of-mysql-insert-statements-in-java-batch-mode-prepared-statements-v