# Inserting huge data into a database in java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

This may be asked a lot but,
so I am trying to insert a 4 million records to a database using java,
I did a lot of googling and tried access and MySQL. Both were almost the same,
with MySQL I tried `statement.addBatch();` but still takes forever.
the question is, what is the best time I can get ? and what is the best way ?

```
        counter++;
        String sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO employees VALUES("some query")";

        sqlState.addBatch(sqlQuery);

        if (counter == 1000) {

            sqlState.executeBatch();

            counter = 0;
        }
```

Also am I using the Batch right ?

Comment: If you **know** the data is consistent you can probably remove all constraints before inserting and add them when done. This should be a tremendous increase in performance.

Comment: How are the records currently stored? Are they in an SQL file?  If so, you should be able to run it as a script directly without the need to use Java.  Just a thought.

Comment: I'd recommend you to check these: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11389449/1065197, http://stackoverflow.com/q/2993251/1065197

Comment: That sounds like an initial load of data. You might want to insert directly, bypassing Java. For MySQL, that would be using [LOAD DATA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/loading-tables.html). And as @ReutSharabani said, removing all indexes and foreign keys during the load will help immensely. It's *much* faster to rebuild an index of 4 million records than it is to insert them one at a time.

Comment: @ReutSharabani i am not following you, i am new to all this

Comment: @Welshboy the records are in an XML file, i am parsing and inserting, if i save them in a .txt file after parsing , will that reduce the time ?

Comment: When you insert a row to an SQL table the database validates the row against aome constraints (primary key, foreign keys ...). The row is also indexed (possibly multiple times. This takes a lot of time and is unnecessary if you **know** the data is valid and you only intend to query it **after** the bulk insert.

Comment: @ReutSharabani i managed to insert 1 billion records in 3 minutes, is that good ?

Comment: "Good" can only be determined with respect to your use case...

Answer (score 0):

Reuse a single PreparedStatements, and set parameters on it for each record, then add it to the batch.

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("Insert into employees (f1, f2, f3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
while (hasMoreRecords) {
  ps.setString(1, "v1");
  ps.setString(2, "v2");
  ....
  ps.addBatch();
  if (++i % 1000 == 0) {
    ps.executeBatch();
  }
}
ps.executeBatch();
```

This won't be a huge difference, but is optimal.

Does your `INSERT` use a sub-query? Maybe that sub-query is slow.

Comment: i will try this. and no, there is no sub query